# How to inject the jenkins credentials actual values to the file

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am having some deployment file as part of the source code it has the two values

**deploy.sh**

```
db_public_key="pub_key"
db_private_key="pri_key"
```

The actual values for those variables are stored in jenkins credentials as secret text

I need to pass the actual values for those variables from jenkins credentals during run time

Jenkins pipeline

```
#!/usr/bin/groovy

pipeline {
    agent any
  

stages{ 

stage("source code") {
            steps {
                sh 'git clone https://xxx:xxx@bitbucket.org/xxx.git'
        }
    }       
 
stage("updating public keys") {
            steps {
                script {
                    withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'data_public_key', variable: 'public_key')]) {
                    sh 'sed -i "s/pub_key/$public_key/g" deploy.sh'
                   }
                 }  
          }
      }   
    }       
}
```

But when I do with sed command its not replacing the actual values instead it is storing
as ****

How can I fetch those values from credentials and replace with actual values in the deploy.sh file in jenkins pipeline

Comment: Environment variables are better than hardcoded secrets in the file. Is it an option for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is not recommended to have sensible values directly in the script. I advice the use of environment variables.

## Override secrets with bash

If you use a secret loaded inside of **withCredentials**, the value is masked with **** (jenkins feature to prevent to show secrets in the log)

```
withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'data_public_key', variable: 'public_key')]) {
  println "inside: "+public_key
}
```

[image]

A workaround is to store it in a global variable and the use it

```
def secretValue;   
withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'data_public_key', variable: 'public_key')]) {
  println "inside: "+public_key
  secretValue = public_key
}
println "outside: "+secretValue
```

[image]

Then you could use the variable as you need.

Note: If yu want to use variables inside pipeline you need to use double quotes instead single quote. Variables inside single quotes are not evaluated.

`sh "sed -i s/pub_key/$secretValue/g deploy.sh"`

Full pipeline here

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('write') {
               steps {
                   script {
                       //just to simulate your deploy.sh file
                       def data = 'db_public_key="pub_key"\ndb_private_key="pri_key"'
                       writeFile(file: 'deploy.sh', text: data)
                       println "initial file content"
                       sh "cat deploy.sh"
                   }
               }
        }
        
        stage('set variables') {
               steps {
                   script {
                    def secretValue;   
                    withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'data_public_key', variable: 'public_key')]) {
                      println "inside: "+public_key
                      secretValue = public_key
                    }
                    //after
                    println "outside: "+secretValue
                    sh "sed -i s/pub_key/$secretValue/g deploy.sh"
                    
                    println "final file content"
                    sh "cat deploy.sh"
                 } 
               }
        }        
    }
}
```

**Result**

[image]

---

## Override secrets with groovy

Anyway if you need to write the values (sensible or not) directly you could use groovy which allows you to use all the java features to do whatever you need

```
def newFileContent = fileContent.replace("pub_key","super-pub-key").replace("pri_key","super-pri-key")
```

Full pipeline here:

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('write') {
               steps {
                   script {
                       //just to simulate your deploy.sh file
                       def data = 'db_public_key="pub_key"\ndb_private_key="pri_key"'
                       writeFile(file: 'deploy.sh', text: data)
                       sh "ls -l"
                       sh "cat deploy.sh"
                   }
               }
        }
        
        stage('set variables') {
               steps {
                   script {
                       def fileContent = readFile "deploy.sh"
                       def newFileContent = fileContent.replace("pub_key","super-pub-key").replace("pri_key","super-pri-key")
                       writeFile(file: 'deploy.sh', text: newFileContent)
                       sh "cat deploy.sh"
                   }
               }
        }        
    }
}
```

**Result**

[image]

---

## Recommended : env variable

As I told you, hardcode secrets in file is a bad practice. You should use environment variables. Also env variables is a part of devops bible https://12factor.net/config

So you script should be:

```
db_public_key="$_SECRET_KEY"
echo "value is: "$db_public_key
```

Then you only need to inject the variable before its execution:

```
env._SECRET_KEY = secretValue
sh '$(pwd)/deploy.sh'
```

Full pipeline here

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('write') {
               steps {
                   script {
                       //just to simulate your deploy.sh file
                       def data = 'db_public_key="$_SECRET_KEY"\necho "value is: "$db_public_key'
                       writeFile(file: 'deploy.sh', text: data)
                       println "initial file content"
                       sh "cat deploy.sh"
                       sh "chmod +x deploy.sh"
                   }
               }
        }
        
        stage('set variables') {
               steps {
                   script {
                    def secretValue;   
                    withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'data_public_key', variable: 'public_key')]) {
                      secretValue = public_key
                    }
                    
                    env._SECRET_KEY = secretValue
                    sh '$(pwd)/deploy.sh'
                 } 
               }
        }        
    }
}
```

**Result**

[image]